# ASP Core 2.0 localizer not finding resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization

I have an asp core app that I am trying to localize. I'll get right into it.

In startup.cs - ConfigureServices:

```
        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

        services.AddMvc()
            .AddViewLocalization(opts => 
                { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

startup.cs - configure:

```
   var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("en"),
        new CultureInfo("fr"),
    };

    app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
    {
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en"),
        // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
        SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
        // UI strings that we have localized.
        SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
    });
```

My resource files are in order. Take `fr` for example (for `HomeController`, `Home` action):
`{root}/Resources/Views/Home/Home.fr.resx`

Here is a View that does not work:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = @Localizer["test"];
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">My Toolboxes</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Notices</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`Title` is always "test", it should be "essai".

When I inspect `Localizer["test"]`, `IsResourceNotFound` = `true`.

I am 100% sure chrome is requesting the `fr` locale:

```
GET /Home/Home HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:62677
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error and in my case it was solved after going to the projects settings and changing **Assembly name** to the exact same value as **Default namespace**. (My Assembly name had been `<MyProjectName>` while my Default namespace was set to `<MyCompany.MyProjectName>`). Internally the LocalizerFactory seems to create the path in which to look for resources based on the assembly name.  If the namespace of your resources do not begin with the assembly name, they will not be found.

Comment: This fixed it for me, thanks. Microsoft should at least give us the option to st a base namespace path for localization to override this behavior.

Comment: Thank you, this was driving me up the walls for a few hours.
My next solution was to hire a priest to exorcise my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddViewLocalization(opts => 
            { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

probably needs to be

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)  // <<< looks like intellisense failed you here...
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

Comment: Isn't that for when you are using different views? I.E. `home.en.cshtml`. In my case, I want to use one view (`home.cshtml`) and multiple resource files (`Views.Home.Home.resx`)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is you are directly setting supported cultures to the app.  And the supported cultures are not registered as part of Service Configuration.  Hence it can't find the culture.
First register your required cultures in ConfigureServices.  Then access those cultures in Configure to set them to app.  See below code:

```js
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //removed other configurations

            services.AddLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });

            // Register cultures here
            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
                opts =>
                {
                    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                    {
                        new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
                        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                        new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
                    };

                    opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
                    opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                    opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
                });

            services.AddMvc()
           
// other registrations
        }
        
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
            IHostingEnvironment env)
{
                       
// Access the registered cultures here and set it to the app

  app.UseRequestLocalization(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);

            app.UseMvc();
}
```